# Extension cannot override default (fallback) templateRootPaths/partialRootPaths/LayoutRootPaths

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I have two extensions:

1. Extension "base_templates" contains a lot of fluid Partials
2. Extension "specific_templates" uses the Partials from "base_templates" and overwrites some of them.

So fluid should use the following order:
1. Check if "specific_templates" has the searched partial
2. Check if "base_templates" has the search partial

So "base_templates" is a fallback for "specific_templates".

To achieve this behaviour I configured partialRootPaths of "specific_templates":

```
plugin.tx_specific_templates {
    view {
        partialRootPaths {
            10 = EXT:base_templates/Resources/Private/Partials/
            20 = EXT:specific_templates/Resources/Private/Partials/
        }
    }
}
```

Since the partialRootPaths.0 is always set to EXT:specific_templates/Resources/Private/Partials/ they always get overwritten by Partials in

Wanted result:

```
array (
  0 => 'BASE_PATH/www/typo3conf/ext/base_templates/Resources/Private/Partials/',
  1 => 'BASE_PATH/www/typo3conf/ext/specific_templates/Resources/Private/Partials/',  
)
```

It works correct for TYPO3 7.x and after update to 8.x not work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when migrating from Typo3 v7 to v8.

I had to alter my TS setup as follows:

```
plugin.tx_specific_templates {
    view {
       partialRootPaths >
       partialRootPaths {
            0 = EXT:base_templates/Resources/Private/Partials/
            1 = EXT:specific_templates/Resources/Private/Partials/
       }
    }
}
```